# Add module as git submodule inside main package

Tags: go

I'm fairly new to golang, and have some issues creating a new module

I want to add a git submodule inside my main package so I can work and make commits to both packages at the same time

The module `http_fs` is added as a git submodule like this

```
git submodule add git@github.com:xxx/http_fs.git repo/http_fs
```

The main package

```
package main

import "repo/http_fs"
```

`go.mod` for `http_fs` module looks like this

```
module github.com/xxx/http_fs

go 1.19
```

When I try to run the main package with `go run main.go` I get this error

```
package repo/http_fs is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/repo/http_fs)
```

File structure

```
./main.go // main package
./repo/http_fs/http_fs.go
```

## update

`go.mod` in the main package

```
module main

go 1.19

replace github.com/xxx/http_fs v1 => ./repo/http_fs
```

Comment: Start by never using file name arguments with go run. Then read go.dev/doc. Your import path is bogus. (And git submodules are locate more in the problem than in the solution space.)

Comment: @Volker I don't understand what you are trying to say?

Comment: I recommended the following: 1. Do not use git submodules (no, not even in your use case), do not use them. 2. Never, literally **never** **ever** do `go run main.go`. Do `go run .` if you cannot accept that Go is a compiled language. 3. Read the "Tutorial"s in https://go.dev/doc/ . Read them again. Try to understand how modules and packages work together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error

```
package repo/http_fs is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/repo/http_fs)
```

is that `go.mod` in `/usr/local/go/src/repo/http_fs` declares the modules `github.com/xxx/http_fs`, not `repo/http_fs`.

You need to import exactly the same module as specified in the `go.mod`, i.e. `github.com/xxx/http_fs`

In `go.mod` of your main module use [`replace`](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) directive:

```
replace github.com/xxx/http_fs v1.2.3 => ./repo/http_fs
```

Replace directive tells compiler where to find the sources of the module.

Comment: Ok, this seems to get rid of the initial error. But now I get a new error `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.` The repo is private. It looks like it wants to clone the repo? I don't want to do that because I already added it as a git submodule?

Comment: What is the best practice to use git submodules in Go? I'm still fairly new to the environment.. I just want to be able to work in both git repositories and push commits

Comment: have updated my question with the content of `go.mod` in the main package